# My R shiny script copies the points to google sheets as "string" and i need points to be in integer format

Tags: r, shiny

I created an app that collects data to google sheets. a text "name" and a number "points". On google sheets, points appears as a string with ' before the number. I would like the user to immediately see points so that the chart can pick them up .

Currently added a third column in google sheets to convert text to value. Not ideal.

Here is the link to the app code: https://github.com/Nxatha/Rshiny-apps/blob/main/trashketballstats.R

Enter data here  to view output:  https://nxatha.shinyapps.io/TrashketballChallenge/

i tried using as.numeric to force the points into numeric but still appears on google sheet as text 'number

Comment: Hi nxatha, Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful you would please share a reproducible example including a small sample of your data set. You will likely get more helpful answers. You can do this best by using You can do this best by using `dput(head(my.example.data))`. Edit your question and include the output of the `structure(...)`.

Comment: i ve provided the link to published app so you can enter data and view output. Hope this suffices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be cbinding, and so getting variables coerced to the most common type, i.e character.
consider and compare

```
cbind(a=1,b="x")
data.frame(a=1,b="x")
```